# How can I access what lanes are configured in an existing JIRA Kanban project?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-agile, kanban

I scanned and searched through https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/ for how to programmatically access what lanes there are for a Kanban board, but the one possible match I found is for status categories, which may or may not be equivalent to Kanban board lanes, at https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4144

What is a good way to query JIRA via API for lanes on a Kanban board?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the GreenHopper REST API, not JIRA REST API. There is a REST browser add-on that may be useful (uncheck the Public API box using a non-Chrome browser). But I didn't see the API to retrieve the columns (or did you mean swimlanes?)